# Gerar mapa infinitamente

Tags: unity3d, lógica, ciclo-infinito

estou desenvolvendo um game e acabei de encontrar uma dificuldade um tanto quanto chata, é um problema de lógica...

Seguinte:
Imagine o cenario do game
[image: Conceito do game]

Aonde, o quadrado preto em que o "Player" está, é a visão da camera
o restando são bolinhas instanciadas em lugares aleatorios do mapa...

- O jogo se trata de um jogo de física, com a mecanica de angry birds, de se arremessar um objeto *

como o player em questão, está sempre avançando para a direita >>>, como posso fazer para que sempre sejam geradas bolinhas novas e apagadas as bolinhas anteriores <<< sendo que a camera sempre ira acompanhar o player?
segue um gif do comportamento o qual desejo:

[http://i.imgur.com/0Ku8g2P.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/0Ku8g2P.gifv)

preciso apenas de um ponto de vista diferente de como montar esta mecanica, problema com lógica mesmo! haha

Obrigado desde ja!
No aguardo

Comment: Acho meio ampla a pergunta, pq vc nao especificou as "regras" pra gerar o cenário. O que eu posso adiantar é que vc pode fazer um mapa de coordenadas (x, y, objeto), e dizer onde as coisas estão (por exemplo, no x 3400, y 200 vai ter uma núvem). Assim, você edita o mapa independente do tamanho da tela. Ao desenhar, basta pegar o que está nas coordenadas da tela (na verdade um pouco maior, pra desenhar coisas que estão fora da tela, mas com algum pedaço já aparecendo). Aleatório fica complicado, a não ser que você esteja fazendo um "Flappy bird", coisas onde o cenário seja descartável.

Comment: Entao, mas no caso eu estou tentando criar algo infinito, não posso especificar um tamanho de comprimento, de altura tudo bem, porem no eixo X, queiro que possa ser infinito o mapa, estarei desabilitando as bolinhas vermelhas que estiverem com uma posicao menor doq a do player + metade da tela, dessa maneira o jogador nao percebe que estao sendo desabilitadas, porem quero que infinitamente as bolinhas sejam geradas a frente do player (no caso a frente das que ja foram geradas)

Comment: Dá na mesma. Basta apagar da lista os objetos que estiverem fora da tela (x < tamanho da maior bolinha) e criar novos dinamicamente. Se preferir, não mova o player, mova as bolinhas todas (mas acho que aí fica mais chatinho de gerenciar). O que vc pode fazer, é depois de um determinado X, fazer um "loop" na fase pro player voltar pro zero depois de um determinado X. Na verdade, é bem simples, o complicado é explicar :)

Comment: mas a partir de que ponto eu posso começar a gerar? pois por exemplo, se gerei bolinhas de x = 0 ate x = 10, quero começar a gerar novas bolinhas em x = 11 ate x = 20

Comment: HMMMMMM, adorei a ideia de zerar o x do player, mas o problema é que o player perceberia, quero algo bem fluido, que gere as bolinhas pra fora do campo de visao do player

Comment: Vá gerando à medida que o player anda. Basta gerar fora da tela. Você pode gerar inicialmente 200 bolinhas, e à medida que vai apagando as que passaram, gera uma nova no lugar.

Comment: Quando eu falo de zerar o X, nao apareceria pulo nenhum. As bolinhas seriam geradas no começo também. Por exemplo, se o X máximo for 20000, por exemplo, as bolinhas seguintes já seriam geradas do zero novamente. Sua rotina de desenho, quando o X passar disso, já pega do zero. Vira um grande loop horizontal. Só que o mapa não se repete,  pois as bolinhas mudam de lugar.

Comment: Entendi, acho que a medida que uma bolinha for apagada, ela ser gerada em uma determinada altura a frente do player é uma boa ideia, a respeito de zerar o X me complicaria para fazer um sistema de distancia percorrida, entao tentarei recriar as bolinhas assim que forem apagadas! obrigado pela opinião :D

Comment: Essa de zerar o X eu falei por vc dizer que quer infinito. Se a distância máxima couber nas variáveis que for usar, nem precisa. Só deixe incrementando o X sem parar, é mais fácil. O problema é se o cara for bom demais, e o número do X não couber no tipo de variável que vc usou. Tem que prever isso no código.

Comment: Certo, tentarei implementar as duas opções então haha, estava com uma ideia diferente em mente, foi bom ver a visão de outra pessoa! Muito obrigado, me ajudou bastante o/

Answer (score 0):

Cara, não seria interessante pra você não movimentar a câmera e o player, e sim somente os obstáculos ?

Porque assim fica muito mais fácil você tratar a mecânica, e a fluidez do game nunca vai ser influenciada. Por exemplo, cada bolinha terá no seu método Update(), uma linha de código que vai diminuir o "transform.position.x", sendo assim elas vão sempre passar pelo player e dar a impressão de progressão, e deste modo você pode ainda estipular um xMin que seria o valor em que ela some da câmera e quando atingir este valor você destrói ela e cria outra nova mais a frente. 
Ficaria algo assim, mais ou menos, pois estou fazendo de cabeca :

```
public float xNovo=15 //Estes valores sao hipoteticos, imagine que o seu player esta 
na posicao 0, e a camera consegue alcancar ate o 10, logo o 15 estaria 5 posicoes a frente.

public float xMin=-15 //Se a camera alcanca ate o 10 para a frente o mesmo vale para tras, 
logo o -15 seria 5 posicoes apos a bolinha ultrapassar a camera

public GameObject novaBolinha; //Aqui voce arrasta o prefab da bolinha

void Update(){
    transform.position= new Vector3(transform.position.x-2,transform.position.y,
    tranform.position.z); // nesta linha a bolinha vai andar constantemente para tras
    e o valor 2 seria a velocidade;

    if(transform.position.x<=xMin){

        float yNovo = Random.Range(10.0f,0.0f); //Esta linha gera um y  aleatorio para o novo 
        obstaculo, lembre que os valores podem variar no seu projeto

        Instantiate(novaBolinha,new Vector3(xNovo, yNovo, 0),transform.rotation); // ira criar 
        a nova bolinha la na frente        

        Destroy(this.gameObject); //Voce destroi o objeto por ultimo por questoes estruturais
        de ordem de execucao
    }    
}
```

Desculpe algum erro no código, mas foi só para tentar expor a ideia, tomara que ajude ! :)